# Importing data from a password protected website using vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I would like to import data from a password protected website(https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Ports/Home.html), i do have the username and the password.

I've tried this VBA code made by Dick in this website: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/11/29/html-tables/ but it doesn't work and get stuck every time i adjust it.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Home.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.UserName.Value = "username"
.Password.Value = "password"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.vesseltracker.com/fr/Port/tangermed/Dashboard.html"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
clip.PutInClipboard
Sheet1.Select
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I really appreciate any help from you. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? I see that you made Internet Explorer visible. Can you see if the logging in works at least?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print "stage x"` lines to tell you which loop you are stuck in.

Comment: It stops at  [Dim clip As DataObject]  !!
Thank you for your help.